# Can a man knowingly marry a woman who can't have children?

Tags: marriage, infertility

This question is not about once a couple is married, as there are previous post that address that topic, the question is can someone start a marriage knowing the women he's marrying can't have kids?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%90_%D7%92 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%9B%D7%92_%D7%90

Comment: How do you know she can't have children?  Sarah also thought she couldn't.

Comment: I'm asking on the medical basis, that there is physiological issues which will prevent her from becoming pregnant, I'm asking a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Rama writes in [Even Ha'Ezer 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> ובזמן הזה נהגו שלא לכוף ע"ז וכן מי שלא קיים פריה ורביה ובא לישא אשה שאינה בת בנים כגון עקרה וזקנה או קטנה משום שחושק בה או משום ממון שלה אע"פ שמדינא היה למחות בו לא נהגו מכמה דורות לדקדק בענין הזיווגים
>
> In this time, its custom that one does not force in regards to this. Likewise he who has not yet fulfilled the mitzvah of being fruitful and multiplying, and he comes to marry a woman who is infertile, for example, a barren woman or an elderly woman, either because he loves her or because she's wealthy; even though according to the letter of the law we should protest his action, however already for many generations the custom has been to not be so precise in the matter of marriages (and let them get married).

See also [Shulchan Aruch, Even Ha'ezer 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.1.8?lang=bi)

Comment: If he already had kids, then we'd mildly prefer he have more because of *baboker zra es zar'echa.* This Rama is saying if he hasn't -- theoretically he really should marry someone who can have kids ... but practically the rabbis stay out of this one.

Comment: @Shalom you're discussing the halacha in 1:8. This answer s quoting from 1:3, where the rama seemingly is going on the mechaber's case of a person not waiting to get married past 20 etc. it seems like the rama is even talking about getting married for the first time.